Aggregation on sub DataFrames defined by sets of indices without loop
Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame, I take some easy example:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"], data = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8), (10, 11)])

I have a set of indices, let's make it simple and random:
inds = [(0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]

I want to aggregate the data according to those indices, in the following way, for instance if the aggregation operation is the mean I would obtain:



A
B




df.loc[inds[0], "A"].mean()
df.loc[inds[0], "B"].mean()


df.loc[inds[1], "A"].mean()
df.loc[inds[1], "B"].mean()


df.loc[inds[2], "A"].mean()
df.loc[inds[2], "B"].mean()



Is there a way to perform this in pure pandas without writing a loop?
This is very similar to a df.groupby and then .agg type of operation, but I did not find a way to create a GroupBy object from a custom set of indices.

can you provide what your expected output looks like

A DataFrame corresponding to the table in the post

Edit: showing how to achieve this with groupby, but surely "significantly simpler to think of this as a selection by index problem"; see the answer by @HenryEcker.

Option 1 (reindex + groupby)
s = pd.Series(inds).explode()

out = df.reindex(s).groupby(s.index).mean()

out

     A    B
0  5.0  6.0 # i.e. A: (1+4+10)/3, B: (2+5+11)/3, etc.
1  4.0  5.0
2  7.0  8.0

Explanation

Use inds to create a pd.Series (here: s), and apply series.explode. The index values function as group identifiers:

# intermediate series ('group 0, 1, 2')

0    0
0    1
0    3
1    0
1    1
1    2
2    1
2    2
2    3
dtype: object


Apply df.reindex with values from s, use df.groupby with s.index, and get groupby.mean.

Option 2 (merge + groupby)
out = (
    df.merge(
        pd.Series(inds, name='g').explode(), 
        left_index=True, 
        right_on='g', 
        how='right'
        )
    .drop(columns=['g'])
    .groupby(level=0)
    .mean()
    )

# same result

Explanation

As with option 1, we create a pd.Series and explode it, but this time we add a name, which we need for the merge in the next step.
Now, use df.merge with how=right to add the values from df using g values from our series and index from df as the keys.
Finally, drop column 'g' (df.drop), apply df.groupby on the index (level=0), and get groupby.mean.


In this case, while it is certainly possible solve through the lens of pandas groupby, it's significantly simpler to think of this as a selection by index problem.
The pandas groupby function is primarily designed to simplify the conversion of data into indices that can be used to identify groups. However, in this case, we're starting with viable index values so we don't need any assistance from a function to create these values again.
We can simply convert our DataFrame to_numpy then use our inds to select the values we want.
df.to_numpy()[inds, :]

# [[[ 1  2]
#   [ 4  5]
#   [10 11]]
# 
#  [[ 1  2]
#   [ 4  5]
#   [ 7  8]]
# 
#  [[ 4  5]
#   [ 7  8]
#   [10 11]]]

From there it's simple to take the mean across whichever dimension we want.
a = df.to_numpy()[inds, :].mean(axis=1)

# [[5. 6.]
#  [4. 5.]
#  [7. 8.]]

This can be turned back into a DataFrame by wrapping it in the constructor
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[inds, :].mean(axis=1), columns=df.columns)

#      A    B
# 0  5.0  6.0
# 1  4.0  5.0
# 2  7.0  8.0

It's even possible to use inds as the index of our DataFrame, if so desired:
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[inds, :].mean(axis=1), columns=df.columns, index=inds)

#              A    B
# (0, 1, 3)  5.0  6.0
# (0, 1, 2)  4.0  5.0
# (1, 2, 3)  7.0  8.0


There are many available ndarray aggregations that are available out of the box, but if needing to perform some custom aggregation use apply_along_axis with a function or lambda expression instead of mean:
def custom_fn(a):
    # Whatever calculations
    return np.mean(a) / np.std(a) + np.ptp(a)


new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.apply_along_axis(custom_fn, 1, df.to_numpy()[inds, :]), 
    columns=df.columns, 
    index=inds
)

#                    A          B
# (0, 1, 3)  10.336306  10.603567
# (0, 1, 2)   7.632993   8.041241
# (1, 2, 3)   8.857738   9.265986


+1. And here I was reading about the XY problem literally just yesterday... That's really nice! Obviously this is what OP should be using.

Great solution for the problem I stated, however I should have taken indices that may not be of the same size, for instance inds = [(0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2, 3)] because my actual problem call for those and this solution does not work in that case while @ouroboros1 's solution do work. Sorry for this mistake

Yeah this approach only scales out if the indicies are regular length. You can, of course, go back to some iteration: a = df.to_numpy() and create a new DF from that new_df = pd.DataFrame([a[i, :].mean(axis=0) for i in inds]). You might consider running some performance tests. There are most certainly sizes of DF where a comprehension over the numpy array is faster than pandas operations. This, of course, depends on your actual aggregation and data.
